# Creating a Yes/NO column for an SLA Report

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

It's highly possible I have gone down the wrong road with my thinking, and trying to unwind from this has gotten me where I am today.  Here...asking for help.

I have built a long Case When statement that tells me when the date of the transaction has to be completed by, excluding weekends and named it "Required SLA Date"

What I'm trying to do is create a column that says, Yes the transaction was completed on or before the SLA Date.  or NO, it was completed after.  My logic was to use the below case statemtent, in ANOTHER case statement that says when the "eventCompleteDate" is > Required SLA then "Yes" else "No" end as MetSLA

```
  CASE WHEN Doc IN ( 'POS', 'Card' )
         THEN CAST(DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                                WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                              END, DateEntered) + ( DATEPART(dw,
                                                          DATEADD(d,
                                                          CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                          DateEntered)
                                                          WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                                          WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                          ELSE 0
                                                          END, DateEntered))
                                                    - 2 + 5 ) % 5
              + ( ( DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                                              WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                              WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                              ELSE 0
                                            END, DateEntered)) - 2 + 5 )
                  / 5 ) * 7 - ( DATEPART(dw,
                                         DATEADD(d,
                                                 CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                          DateEntered)
                                                   WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                                   WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                   ELSE 0
                                                 END, DateEntered)) - 2 ) AS DATE)
         ELSE CAST(DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                                WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                ELSE 0
                              END, DateEntered) + ( DATEPART(dw,
                                                          DATEADD(d,
                                                          CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                          DateEntered)
                                                          WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                                          WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                          ELSE 0
                                                          END, DateEntered))
                                                    - 2 + 10 ) % 5
              + ( ( DATEPART(dw, DATEADD(d, CASE DATEPART(dw, DateEntered)
                                              WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                              WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                              ELSE 0
                                            END, DateEntered)) - 2 + 10 )
                  / 5 ) * 7 - ( DATEPART(dw,
                                         DATEADD(d,
                                                 CASE DATEPART(dw,
                                                          DateEntered)
                                                   WHEN 7 THEN 2
                                                   WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                   ELSE 0
                                                 END, DateEntered)) - 2 ) AS DATE)
    END AS 'Required SLA Date'
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @NenadZivkovic I want to create a column in my qry that says Yes, the event was completed by the required sla data (I attached the code) or NO, it didn't get completed by the required sla data

Comment: @NenadZivkovic and thanks for editing it to make it more readable.  I have no luck trying to do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a nested query (or a CTE) to avoid writing the logic twice.

```
SELECT RequiredSlaDate, 
       case when RequiredSlaDate > EventCompleteDate then 'NO' 
            else 'YES' 
       end as MetSLA
FROM
(
   SELECT EventCompleteDate, 
          CASE WHEN Doc -- etc, etc ...
          AS RequiredSlaDate
   FROM Table
 ) as Source
```

Comment: I don't think I'm grasping how to do a case statement in a CTE, nor do I know how to do a case statement in a nested query in the from clause

Comment: @donviti, in the above example, you put your whole SELECT with CASE in the subquery, and then just select * from it, adding you Yes/No column. I will write you a CTE example

Comment: AHHHHHHH I GOT IT!  YOU ROCK.   This was taking me hours!  hours!  Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a example of CTE Solution. Your whole query you had up to now goes inside the CTE, and select from CTE just adds a new column:

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
   SELECT CASE WHEN Doc IN ( 'POS', 'Card' )
               THEN .... --your whole CASE from above goes here, I will not copy/paste
          END AS [Required SLA Date],
     eventCompleteDate,
     YourOtherColumns -- also all other columns you are selecting in your query
   FROM
   YourTable
)
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN eventCompleteDate > [Required SLA Date] THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS MetSLA
FROM CTE
```

**[SQLFiddle VERY Simplified DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/91cd5/5)**

PS: Also note that you shouldn't be using quotation marks when you name your column as in `AS 'Required SLA Date'` but square brackets instead `AS [Required SLA Date]`. If nothing else for readability.

Comment: I did make that change with the column names. I really appreciate your assistance!